# How to include Javascript libraries in a Grunt project?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, project, bower

I'm trying to learn a modern Javascript workflow for client-side development, so I'm giving a try to Grunt.

I want to require some libraries like *AngularJS*, *Bootstrap* or *moment.js* and have them installed in my `dist` directory. If possible I would like to have some package management for them.

I've given a look at *Bower* and *grunt-bower-task*, but I'm not sure up to which point they are suitable for this task, as not all packages include minified versions and *grunt-bower-task* seems to ignore those anyway.

Is there a Grunt-friendly package management solution to manage client-side Javascript libraries or should I keep downloading them to a `vendor` folder and just tell Grunt to copy them to the `dist` folder in their `.js` or `.min.js` variant?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *manage client-side Javascript libraries* ?

Comment: Those which will be processed by the end-user browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think bower and grunt have different responsabilities. Bower for client package management and grunt for building (and other tasks). At least I use them for that. Installing angularjs and bootstrap with bower, it downloads both minified and development libraries. If not you can always minified them with grunt.

And yes, i believe that controlling your packages with bower and building your application with grunt (using copy, concat, uglify, etc. tasks) is the best practice.

You can check Component also, its an equivalent for bower.

Comment: What about `grunt-bower-task`? Is it worth it with your approach?

Comment: To be honest, i haven't used it, i guess i don't need to. By that i don't mean it is not useful, but for me **bower install xxxx --save** using .bowerrc is a less frequent step than running jshint before running mocha tests, and for that i use grunt. I guess its just matter of preferences...

Comment: I ended doing that. I use bower to get the libraries in `bower_components` and then I tell Grunt to copy the required files to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to hack something like this up once using [`grunt-curl`](https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-curl) - just defining a list of libraries I wanted to include, and downloading them from [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/), which I believe keeps the links updated to current versions. I did this within a separate `install` task.

It wasn't the most elegant solution, but it did what I needed at the time. I probably wouldn't suggest it if you're wanting stronger control of the packages (ie. versions) you use - but then again if you do, why not just use Bower?